# Can you text a business/sole trader promotional material if they put their number online?

Tags: united-kingdom, telemarketing, spam, texting

eg. An electrician has put their mobile number on a website to attract business. Can I legally contact that electrician to tell them about a product that he/she may be interested in? .. Everything is based in the united kingdom.

Comment: What makes you think that the number you see can receive text messages? Many businesses operate from land lines, not cell phones. What country are you asking about?

Comment: Hi Ron, The United Kingdom.

Answer (score 3):

No.

From [here](https://www.bulksms.com/resources/regulations/uk-regulations-on-commercial-sms-messaging-and-marketing.htm):

> Organisations must not send marketing texts to individuals without
>   their specific, valid and prior explicit consent. This consent must be
>   recorded and kept as proof of consent. There is a limited exception
>   for previous customers, which is known as the soft opt-in. A soft-opt
>   in only applies if the organisation have obtained the contact details
>   in the course of a sale (or negotiations for a sales) of a product or
>   service to the customer; they are only marketing their own similar
>   products or services; and they gave the customer an opportunity to
>   opt-out of the marketing, both when first collecting the details and
>   in every message thereafter.

Comment: Thanks Greendrake, could it not be argued that putting your number online for people to contact you is consent.

Comment: @jon Nope, because they put it online to be contacted regarding _specific_ purpose. This does not constitute consent to be contacted just about anything.

Comment: thanks.. I hear you.. though it seems very unfair that businesses setting up today can't reach out to potential customers with targeted messages, without having to pay huge advertising costs to companies that all got away with spamming back in the day. I mean how can you get a potential customer give you permission to contact them without you first contacting them?

Comment: @jon Do you like spam? Or do you think your proposal is any different from spam? Certainly there will be a chance that some of your recipients are glad you contacted them, but the vast majority will be annoyed. Do you think it is fair to annoy 95% of people to get 5% satisfied? Then, market is about the balance of supply and demand, not about fairness. You either afford lawful advertising, or you are out.

Comment: true, but I would say there is a marked difference between someone that sends 1000 one time messages to people that may well have a legitimate interest in the message than someone that sends out multiple messages to a million random people.. I would consider the first to be legit marketing and the second spam. As I understand it, this used to be case.

Comment: @jon Although I might welcome a targeted advertisement through some means, text message isn't one of them.  If you are legitimately selling a service you think the recipient will like to only those who will be interested, you can afford to take the trouble to do it right (perhaps in the mail).  If it's not worth it to you to do more than send out texts, you're spamming.

Comment: Hi David, I agree that advertising a business requires more than sending out some texts.. but I wanted to find out the legality of sending texts. It appears that legally the only way to contact a potential customer 'unsolicited' is by cold calling them. I know I'd rather receive a text than a phone call... I think the law should be expanded to differentiate between direct marketing and spamming.